# PHP won't delete from MySQL

Tags: php, database, mysql

The PHP code won't delete item from database using "$noteid". If I put a number in it's place it will, but when I try using "$noteid". It won't do it. It does everything correct up to the point where it tries to delete.

Here's how I get the "$noteid":

```
//javascript
function viewnote(noteid) {

  window.location = "noteview.php?noteid="  + noteid;

}

//button in body
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="editnote('<?= $noteid ?>')" />
```

Here's the code on the linked to page:

```
<?php

$noteid = $_REQUEST['noteid'];

if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE noteid='$noteid'");
 header ('Location: index2.php');
}
?>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" style="margin:0px; pading:0px"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></form>
</body>
```

---

** It's Working Now!!! **
What made it work was a hidden form field.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $nid = $_REQUEST['notenum'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE noteid='$nid'");
    header ('Location: index2.php');
}
?>

//body cody
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" style="margin:0px; pading:0px"><input type="text" name="notenum" value="<?php echo $noteid; ?>" style="display:none" /><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></form>
```

Thanks to everyone for your help!!! This site is my favourite site now.

Comment: The likelihood is that $_REQUEST['noteid'] is empty.  Try `vardump($_REQUEST)` and see what you're working with.

Comment: $noteid = "'; drop table notes; --";

Comment: Note that `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` is a potential XSS hole, too. It should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that `$_REQUEST['noteid']` won't be set after the form has posted. In that scenario you could add a hidden form field to store the value from the query string. You also need to look at sanitising your variable with `mysql_real_escape_string` and using `$_GET` or `$_POST` rather than `$_REQUEST`

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!! I forgot about using hidden form fields. I'm still new to PHP. Y'all are great help :)

Comment: @dnagirl gave you some good advice. If a variable doesn't behave correctly, always start by dumping it.

Answer (score 5):

You're using a lot of bad practices:

```
<?= $noteid ?>
```

That is not supported on all PHP versions, use the following instead:

```
<?php echo $noteid; ?>
```

Secondly,

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE noteid='$noteid'");
```

STOP RIGHT THERE. [Go learn about SQL injection before coding.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) I'm not joking.
The right code:

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM notes WHERE noteid="'.mysql_real_escape_string($noteid).'"');
```

Also ensure that the PHP variable `$noteid` does exist prior to `onclick="editnote(...)" />`.

Comment: ok changed everything around and code is still not working. The <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="editnote('<?= $noteid ?>')" /> is generated from $getnotes = mysql_query(" code removed for safety reasons ", $db); if (mysql_num_rows($getnotes)>0) { while($gnote = mysql_fetch_array($getnotes)){ $title = $gnote['title']; $noteid = $gnote['noteid'];}}   It definitely exists prior, because if it didn't, I wouldn't be able to go to the next page using the number pulled from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using [Binds and Prepared statements](http://devzone.zend.com/article/686). Almost all problems of the from "x from PHP doesn't work right in SQL" can be solved by using prepared statements.